# linux cut command with field-value condition

Tags: linux, bash, awk, field, cut

I am trying to figure out a linux shell command which will display portion of a field from a log satisfying condition of other field.

**Sample log-file**:

```
2013-04-15;admin@abc.com;111111@abc.com;outgoing;24;headline
2013-04-15;222222@abc.com;admin@abc.com;incoming;0;chat
2013-04-15;admin@abc.com;333333@abc.com;outgoing;26;headline
2013-04-15;444444@abc.com;333333;incoming;12;chat
2013-04-16;444444@abc.com;555555;incoming;0;chat
```

I tried to display only the unique numbers from field 2 and 3 separated by delimiter ';' where field 5 != 0

**Sample expected output:**

```
111111
333333
444444
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk -F";" '$5!=0{print $2, $3}' fields.txt | grep -o '[0-9]\+' | sort -u
111111
333333
444444
```

Explanation: extract columns 2 and 3 based on column 5 value; match only the numbers; eliminate duplicates

Comment: You're welcome.  Please mark this as the answer if it's what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -Po '\d+(?=([^;]*;)?[^;]*;[^;]+;[^0][^;]*;[a-z]+$)' logfile|sort -u
```

Should be self-explanatory. lol.

Comment: It works but i haven't not got it. I am kind of new to linux, so if u kindly provide an explanation that would be better. Thanks in advance.